# Zapier - Create Instant Triggers

Tags: node.js, zapier

I'm using Zapier's CLI developer kit to create some app. But when I create a "new object" trigger, the url supplied in official document looks just like a "get all" trigger:

```
method: 'GET',
url: 'http://example.com/api/objects'
```

Seems Zapier won't know when a new object is created instantly, instead, Zapier checking all the objects every 5 mins.

Their [plans](https://zapier.com/app/billing/plans) shows even the most expensive plan can just provide checking every 5 mins.

So how can I create instant triggers? That said, I want to send a request to Zapier every time an object is created in my app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Webhook also called RestHook you can create an Instant Trigger in Zapier. 
If your API didn't support Webhooks then first implement webhook in your API

You can found more about the Webhooks at 
 https://realtimeapi.io/hub/rest-hooks/

Here is a Zapier Sample APP with Instant Trigger implemented
https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-example-app-rest-hooks

Zapier Documentation about the RstHook 
https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v2/rest-hooks/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Webhooks if you want triggers to fire instantly.

https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-example-app-rest-hooks

Answer (score 0):

Webhooks works greate for such by using catchook zapier method

And Sometimes for time-saving we use email as triggering emails are instant and we send the objects in subject and content then we crop them in parse or formatter